# Android make a dialog appear in fullscreen without using requestWindowFeature

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 dialogNewdata = new Dialog(this);
 dialogNewdata.requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 ialogNewdata.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_newacticity);
 dialogNewdata.show();
```

I used this code but `Dialog` not open in full screen, `dialogNewdata` getting `wrap_content` size

Comment: i went through your comments do you want to display your status bar when you display the alert ? or without status bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
dialogNewdata.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT);
```

Try this code after

```
dialogNewdata.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   Window window = dialog.getWindow();
   window.setLayout((int) (display.getWidth()), (int)(display.getHeight()));
   dialog.show();
```

Try the below code... Hope it works.

Comment: sorry .. status bar and my dialog overlap in your solution

Comment: @Satishpethani then put a id on Your ParentLayout in xml.. and get the width and height through the java program and set it to the window.setLayout(width, height).. it will work

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways:

1.use:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```

2.use `windowmanager`

```
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int width, height;
    LayoutParams params;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    } else {
        Point point = new Point();
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        width = point.x;
        height = point.y;
    }

    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```

this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For full screen `Dialog`

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);  // test is your layout you display in your alert
dialog.show();
```

**Note:** About the Theme used;

`Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` is a variant of `Theme_Black`that has *no title bar and no status bar*. This theme sets `windowFullscreen` to `true`.  [so don't need to measure height]

That is why you get it as full screen. Also by default its black (without it's `setContentView`)

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you

```
   final WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    wlmp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    wlmp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wlmp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
```

before

```
 dialog.show()
```